# REST Response is {}

Tags: rest, jersey-2.0

I am new to REST. I have written a small REST resource and Whenever I try to invoke the REST service from POSTMAN, i get a empty response {} and status code 200

The Request :

http://localhost:8080/demo/managers

```
@GET
@Path("managers")
@Produces({"application/json"})
public Response getManagers() throws GeneralException, JSONException

{
            JSONArray valueString = COMING_FROM_OTHER_METHOD();
            System.out.println("==== "+valueString.toString());

            return Response.ok(valueString,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
          }
```

The correct value I can see in System.out.println():

```
[{"display":"john","id":"003"},{"display":"hansi","id":"004"},{"display":"samy gayle","id":"005"}]
```

I want to a JSONArray Response but everytime I get an empty response

```
{}
```

But when modify the code like below it gives correct response

```
@GET
@Path("managers")
@Produces({"application/json"})
public String getManagers() throws GeneralException, JSONException

{
            JSONArray valueString = COMING_FROM_OTHER_METHOD();
            System.out.println("==== "+valueString.toString());

            return valueString.toString();
          }
```

Kindly Help. why am I getting {} when trying to return a Response object J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use domain objects rather than `String` instances:

```
class Manager {
  private String id;
  private String display;
  ... setters/getters ...
}

public ResponseEntity<ArrayList<Manager>> getManagers() throws GeneralException {
  ArrayList<Manager> managers = COMING_FROM_OTHER_METHOD();
  return new ResponseEntity<>(managers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```